# how to SMS notification send by laravel

Tags: notifications, sms

I have Paid Bulk Sms Panel but not setup how to customer buy product after send sms by laravel project.
Please help me anyone

API URL (GET & POST) : http://sms.natoreit.com/smsapi?api_key=(APIKEY)&type=text&contacts=(NUMBER)&senderid=(Approved Sender ID)&msg=(Message Content)

route

```
{
  type : "post",
  url : "http://sms.natoreit.com/smsapi",
  data : {
    "api_key" : "{your api key}",
    "senderid" : "{sender id}",
    "type" : "{content type}",
    "scheduledDateTime" : "{schedule date time}",
    "msg" : "{your message}",
    "contacts" : "88017xxxxxxxx+88018xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Route::post('/order/confirm','WelcomeController@order_confirm')->name('order_confirm');

public function order_confirm($id)

{

?????????????????????????

}

Need to SMS Send Customer phone number

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel SMS API plugin](https://github.com/gr8shivam/laravel-sms-api) to send SMS easily in Laravel.

You need to define your SMS Gateway config in `config/sms-api.php`.

Once done, you can use it as:

```
smsapi()->gateway('GATEWAY_NAME')->sendMessage("TO", "Message");
```